# VBA Exce IF statement for file save under custom name

Tags: excel, vba

I want to set the IF statement for the file saving macro under the custom name.
The problem is, that this file cannot be saved under one name only. There is a string, which requires another name.

For this purpose, I prepared the code as per below, which unfortunately doesn't work.

```
Sub SaveAsB()
Dim name As String, name2 As String, name3 As String, name4 As String, custom_name As String ', path As String

     Dim fs As Worksheet
     Set fw = Sheets("Frontsheet")
     name = fw.Range("AA9")
     name2 = fw.Range("D18")
     name3 = fw.Range("D38")
     custom_name = name & "_" & name2 & "_v." & name3 & ".0"
     'path = ThisWorkbook.path & "\" & ActiveWorkbook.name
     If name3.Value = "As-built" Then
     custom_name = name & "_" & name2 & "AS-BUILT"
     End If

     Application.DisplayAlerts = False
     ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs filename:=custom_name, FileFormat:=52

    End Sub
```

I am getting an error: **Invalid qualifier** - for the `If name3.Value = "As-built" Then` line

Shall I base my IF statement directly on the cell value?

**UPDATED:**

```
Sub SaveAsB()
Dim name As String, name2 As String, name4 As String, custom_name As String


Dim fs As Worksheet
Set fw = Sheets("Frontsheet")

Dim name3 As Range

name = fw.Range("AA9")
name2 = fw.Range("D18")
name3 = fw.Range("D38")
 custom_name = name & "_" & name2 & "_v." & name3 & ".0"
 'path = ThisWorkbook.path & "\" & ActiveWorkbook.name
 If name3.Value = "As-built" Then
 custom_name = name & "_" & name2 & "_v." & name3 & ".0 AS-BUILT"
 End If

 Application.DisplayAlerts = False
 ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs filename:=custom_name, FileFormat:=52

  End Sub
```

The debugger highlights now name3 = `fw.Range("D38")`, and says

**Object variable or with block variable not set**

Comment: excplicitly declare `Dim name3 As Range`. You may want to add `Option Explicit` at the very top of your module and hence be forced to explicitly declare all variables type

Comment: And then use `Set name = fw.Range("AA9")` etc.

Comment: You've declared them as Strings in which case when you assign them from a cell, include `.Value` eg. `name = fw.Range("AA9").Value` but thereafter when referring to the string don't use `.Value` - eg. `If name3 = "As-built" Then`

Comment: @MariuszKruklar: dim `As Range` all variables that have to be of that type (at least those in stataments like `... = fw.Range("..")` and the likes and then `Set` them

Comment: I did as you said, but the error is exactly the same as in my code updated. Maybe shall I do sth with With statement? At least error prompts that.

Comment: @MariuszKrukar, your last code does NOT reflect my last comment suggestions: please read them carefully (I was speaking about "all" variables deserving the same treatment)

Comment: This is what I have got now:

Comment: Dim name As Range, name2 As Range, name3 As Range, name4 As Range, custom_name As String

Comment: if you're still facing any issue then please update your question with actual code and describe the corresponding issues

Answer (score 0):

Basically I should have change the one line of my code, which currently looks like this:

```
Sub SaveAsB()
Dim name As String, name2 As String, name3 As String, name4 As String, custom_name As 
String, filename As String


Dim fs As Worksheet
Set fs = Sheets("Frontsheet")


name = fs.Range("AA9")
name2 = fs.Range("D18")
name3 = fs.Range("D38")
custom_name = name & "_" & name2 & "_v." & name3 & ".0"
path = ThisWorkbook.path & "\" & ActiveWorkbook.name
If fs.Range("D38").Value = "As-built" Then
custom_name = name & "_" & name2 & "_v." & name3 & ".0 AS-BUILT"
End If

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs filename:=custom_name, FileFormat:=52

End Sub
```

Instead of `If name 3.Value` I put `If fs.Range("D38").Value = "As-built"` Then

Comment: the real "basically" (i.e. the minum effort to make THIS piece fo code work) is that you should have used `if name3 = "As-built" Then` as CLR posted in comments. And that is because you are using the default `Value` property of Range object, while `String` are not objects and don't have any property.